# Is it good practice to use buttons for images while developing ios apps?

Tags: ios, swift, battery

I am developing an app in swift 3 for IOS 10 currently and have came across a...not a problem... but I don't feel like I am doing this the right way. I have a table view with images in some of them, and for the images, I used buttons rather than using an image view. I do this because I need the user to interact with it. I fully understand that UIImageViews can allow user interaction and use a tap gesture recognizer but, my question is, is it worth it for me to re-program it with an image view or are buttons fine. I what I am doing bad practice, will it slow down my app, will it destroy battery life, are there any problems with it?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a button with an image in it is fine, and very common.

It has a number of advantages over clickable image views, in fact:

It lets you set target/action links in interface builder, just like normal buttons.

You get highlighting behavior for free, and can make buttons that toggle between states quite easily.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I'm glad to know that it is very common, though I still may switch for the gestures. Anyways, thanks!